# Issues using NSNumberFormatter?

Tags: xcode, nsstring, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to make a label to show the temperature, with a maximum of 3 digits for temperatures over a 100, but I don't want any decimals...

```
    NSString *longtempstring = [tmp description];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:3];
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
    NSString *shorttempstring = [formatter stringForObjectValue:[NSString  stringWithString:longtempstring]];
```

The code above always returns (null)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `nil` because the object you are passing to `stringForObjectValue:` is not of the type expected.

First of all, don't use `stringForObjectValue:`. That is a member of the parent class, `NSFormatter`. `NSNumberFormatter` has more specific methods that avoid confusion of object types like `numberFromString:` and `stringFromNumber:`.

Second, `NSNumberFormatter` is used to go from number to formatted string or formatted string to number. Not directly from formatted string to formatted string. You will need to use one number formatter to read your original string and produce a number and another to produce a new shorter formatted string from that number.

Of course, you might be able to make the first step (from long string to number) easier by using `NSScanner` or by taking a substring of your long string (cutting out everything except for the number itself) and then using the `NSString` method `integerValue` or `doubleValue`. A regular expression could also be used to extract the number from the first (longer) string.

The long and short of it is, this is a two step process. The first step (getting a number) can be accomplished any number of ways and a `NSNumberFormatter` might not be the easiest way. The second step (getting a new shorter string) is what `NSNumberFormatter` is perfect for.

Comment: I fixed it by converting the NSString to an NSNumber and only pulling the integer value from the string, thus removing any decimals. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by converting the NSString to an NSNumber and only pulling the integer value from the string, thus removing any decimals.

```
        NSString *longtempstring = [tmp description];
        NSNumber *tempintegervalue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[longtempstring integerValue]];
        NSString *shorttempstring = [tempintegervalue stringValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *longtempstring = [tmp description];
```

What is the value of `longtempstring` here? Is it even a number?

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:3];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
```

Why do you set maximum fraction digits to `3` if you say that you don't want any fraction digits? Fraction digits are what is "after the dot" and you say you don't want any decimals. If you don't want any decimals, minimum and maximum must be set to `0`.

```
NSString *shorttempstring = [formatter stringForObjectValue:[NSString  stringWithString:longtempstring]];
```

First of all, why are you copying the string? `[NSString stringWithString:...]` creates a new string that is a copy of the string you provide as argument. Strings are immutable, there is no need to copy them, they won't be modified. If you are afraid that a `NSString` may in fact be a `NSMutableString`, after all that is a subclass of `NSString` and you want to copy it, just **copy it** by calling `[aString copy]`. `copy` is a very smart method here. If the `NSString` is in fact a mutable string, it will really copy it, so you get an immutable copy. If it is not a mutable string, though, `copy` just returns the same string with a retain count increased by one (so in that case `copy` behaves exactly like `retain`). However, in your case copying makes no sense whatsoever.

And second, what makes you believe, that you can feed a string into a `NSNumberFormater`? It is called `NSNumberFormater` because it formats objects of type `NSNumber`. How is a `NSString` a `NSNumber`? It is not called `NSStringFormater`. If you feed an object of the wrong class to a formater, it will return `nil`, that's how this method is documented.

If your `longtempstring` contains a number with fraction, e.g. `12.345`, then the correct code would look like this:

```
NSString * longtempstring = [tmp description];
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
NSNumber * tempnumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[longtempstring doubleValue]];
NSString * shorttempstring = [formatter stringForObjectValue:tempnumber];
```

However, if all you want to do is cut off the decimals, that is a horrible way to do it. This can be done much more effective:

```
double d;
NSString * longtempstring;
NSString * shorttempstring;

longtempstring = @"12.345";
d = [longtempstring doubleValue];
shorttempstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)d];
```

This is much shorter, needs less memory, and is at least three times faster. If you want to round the number (that means everything with a fraction `.5` and above is rounded to the next higher value), just round it:

```
d = round([longtempstring doubleValue]);
```